# Are interactions with quadratic terms in MARS possible?

Tags: interaction, mars

I am using the mars function of the R earth package. When the degree of interaction of MARS terms is at least 1, is it possible to have quadratic terms like x1*x1 in the model? I guess interactions between different hinge functions are possible. What about raw input variables like x1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes with some modification.

On its own, MARS won't try to take higher-order functions of the predictors. MARS can only include three types of basis functions:

1. A constant
2. A hinge function
3. Interactions of hinge functions

You can "trick" MARS into including a quadratic term by making a new variable `xnew = x1*x1` then fitting MARS. MARS will not derive this `xnew` variable on its own, though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and a solution/trick :-)